# Linear Programming Problem about optimal solution

Tags: linear-programming

> Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ are the optimum solutions of LPP, then
>
> (a) $X = λX_1+(1- λ)X_2$, $λ \in \Bbb R$ is also an optimal solution
>
> (b) $X = λX_1+(1-λ)X_2$, $0 \leq λ \leq 1$ gives an optimal solution
>
> (c) $X = λX_1+(1+λ)X_2$, $0 \leq λ \leq 1$ gives an optimal solution
>
> (d) $X = λX_1+(1+λ)X_2$, $λ \in \Bbb R$ gives an optimal solution

Please explain (in detail) how to solve it...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A set $K$ is called convex if $X_1, X_2 \in K$ and for  $0 \leq λ \leq 1 :$ $λ X_1+(1- λ )X_2 \in K$, that means that each convex combination of two points of $K$ is also a point of $K$. In other words if $X_1,X_2$ are the optimal solutions of LPP, then (b) $X = λX_1+(1-λ)X_2$, $0 \leq λ \leq 1$ gives an optimal solution. A convex combination of $x_1,x_2$ is each point $x$ of the form:$$x=\Sigma_{i=1}^{k}{λ_ix_i}$$ with $λ_i \geq 0$ and $\Sigma_{i=1}^{k}λ_i=1$